Minimal Template to create Azure Enterprise app
I'm trying to automate the process of creating an Azure Enterprise Application with Deployment Scripts, but I'm getting the error:

DeploymentScriptError: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Does anyone know what kind of permissions I need and how I can add them through the ARM template?
This is my template so far:
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {
    },
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        },
        "entAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Enterprise Application"
            }
        },
        "identityName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the User Assigned Identity"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
            "apiVersion": "2023-01-31",
            "name": "[parameters('identityName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
            "name": "[guid(resourceGroup().id, 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/read')]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', 'acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('identityName')), '2023-01-31').principalId]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
            "apiVersion": "2023-08-01",
            "name": "runShellScript",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "AzureCLI",
            "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('identityName'))]": {}
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('identityName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "azCliVersion": "2.9.1",
                "scriptContent": "
                    az login --identity
                    # Create Enterprise Application
                    az ad app create --display-name $1
                ",
                "arguments": "[parameters('entAppName')]",
                "timeout": "PT5M",
                "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
                "retentionInterval": "P1D"
            }
        }
    ]
}


@VinayB But, "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy" is not an Azure AD Role, it's MS Graph permissions and cannot be assigned to a user performing the deployment.

We can get this privilege under application developer or application administrator role for SP @Woitek1993

@VinayB Thank you for the reply. Would it be a problem to show me an example? I can't find a way to do it from ARM Template and I have to do it fully automatically.

Have you tried automatically create microsoft graph resource in bicep instead of using deployment script ? something like this, it is a new feature in bicep, It's much more simple than command-line in json arm templates.
provider microsoftGraph

var entraIDRole = 'f2ef992c-3afb-46b9-b7cf-a126ee74c451'
resource resourceApp 'Microsoft.Graph/applications@v1.0' = {
  uniqueName: 'ExampleResourceApp'
  displayName: 'Example Resource Application'
  appRoles: [
    {
      id: entraIDRole
      allowedMemberTypes: [ 'User', 'Application' ]
      description: 'Read access to resource app data'
      displayName: 'ResourceAppData.Read.All'
      value: 'ResourceAppData.Read.All'
      isEnabled: true
    }
  ]
}

resource resourceSp 'Microsoft.Graph/servicePrincipals@v1.0' = {
  appId: resourceApp.appId
}

reference documents:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/identity/bicep-templates-for-microsoft-graph-resources/
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-governance-and-management/announcing-public-preview-of-bicep-templates-support-for/ba-p/4141772
https://dev.to/omiossec/using-azure-bicep-to-deploy-ms-graph-resources-gh#:~:text=In%20the%20main.,will%20be%20shown%20as%20unknow.

As I understand it use virtual machine instead of deployment script to execute the commands. The biggest problem I have with this is that I probably need a global administrator role to do so, but I can't guarantee that the costumer will be having that.

Application Administrator may be suitable here.
